# Pros and Cons of a BCS integration versus a Custom Integration

Tags: bcs

What are the pros and cons of using the BCS to integrate an external system into SharePoint versus a custom integration.

Comment: You will find a discussion here:
http://www.layer2.de/en/community/FAQs/BDLC/Pages/Feature-comparision-sharepoint-external-list.aspx

Think its not about "custom" only. Possibly a 3rd party app can do more compared to OOB BCS, especially with SharePoint 2013 or SPO/cloud. 3rd party tools avoid programming, and can offer all native list features, e.g. search, change notifications, workflows - not only displaying external data on SharePoint surface...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pros

**End User**

- Business Data Web Parts & External List can render data out of the box
- Enterprise & FAST Search Integration with Managed Property Mapping support
- User Profile Synchronization
- Office Integration via External Data Column
- Office Mapping for Tasks,Contacts and Calendar
- SharePoint Workspace Support
- Single Sign on Support
- Workflow support via External Data Column and External List

**Developer**

- Visual Studio Tooling Support
- SharePoint Designer Support
- Out of the box support for existing SQL Databases & WebServices
- .Net Assembly Connector can connect to any other datatype
- Server side API to develop custom web parts against
- Client Side API to develop custom client integrations against
- Write once work against any data source controls are possible

### Cons

**End User**

- Out of the Box Web Parts look outdated
- External Data Column data needs to be refreshed

**Developer**

- Generation and Maintenance of Model file is time consuming.
- Data Model does not support subclassing.
- Writing controls that work against any data source is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Fabian Williams had a related post about the topic (BCS vs Alternates) a few months ago -
     http://www.sharepointfabian.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=202